# quotes in javascript function

Tags: javascript, quotes

I need a bit of help with quotes in javascript function

```
function jsNewWindow(value){
        //window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow"); 
        window.open("rpt_Distance.php?POST_IN1="+value+","mywindow","width=800,height=600") ;
    }
```

thanks!

Comment: sorry. I was running out the door. Pardon my manners. Really appreciate help at this board!

Comment: @delnan Well, it's not that bad. There are only 4 lines of code and I believe that everybody immediately noticed the extra quote. I think this question doesn't deserve such a harsh label. I've seen worse :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"rpt_Distance.php?POST_IN1=" + value, "mywindow", "width=800,height=600"

Comment: I see two changes here, as compared to other posts so far. A $ was inserted before POST_IN1. And the + after the word value was removed.

Comment: @DOK it appears the question was edited after I posted my answer.  I will adjust it to reflect the current portion of the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
function jsNewWindow(value){
        //window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow"); 
        window.open("rpt_Distance.php?$POST_IN1="+value,"mywindow","width=800,height=600") ;
    }
```

I just removed `+"`

Comment: Why was this down voted, it looks like it was a correct change as the resulting JS it sntacticaly correct?

Comment: I made a mistake in my first draft ;-) Net was slow took me few mins to update and someone downvoted. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It helps if you ask a question, not just post a snippet function. Are you trying to insert actual quotes? If so escape them with '\'.

EDIT: Hats off to Shoban for being able to read minds (and code) :).

Comment: This seems to me like a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I tried to add an answer (escaping quotes), but when I don't know the exact question I generally try to get clarification.

Comment: josh.trow only have 46 rep, you need 50 to add comments directly to the question.

Answer (score 1):

You have one `+"` that must be removed:

```
window.open("rpt_Distance.php?$POST_IN1="+value+","mywindow","width=800,height=600") ;
```

must be replaced by:

```
window.open("rpt_Distance.php?$POST_IN1="+value,"mywindow","width=800,height=600") ;
```

Answer (score 1):

This code should read to be correct - leaving out the +" after value

```
function jsNewWindow(value){
    //window.open ("http://www.javascript-coder.com","mywindow"); 
    window.open("rpt_Distance.php?$POST_IN1="+value,"mywindow","width=800,height=600") ;
}
```